# How to transfer data to a template without using EJS?

Tags: html, node.js, rest, embedded-javascript

```
app.get("/movies", function(req, res) {
  Movies.find({}, function (err, foundMovie){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("movies/index", {movie_index:foundMovie});
    }
  }
});
```

I have this code that finds a movie and send that foundMovie to an EJS file. The route is created following RESTful routes. I can display anything about that foundMovie in my EJS file as I please. The EJS file then takes the foundMovie and manipulates it. Then the EJS file will be rendered by the **app.js** on the mentioned route.

**My questions are following:**

1- Since I dont wanna use EJS, how will transfer the data/foundMovie from the app.js to an HTML file.

2 - How will I use the data/foundMovie **inside** HTML file without using the EJS syntax (<%= movie_index.name%>)

**Note:** KIndly state your answer for NodeJS environment only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data rendered as HTML by the server, you use some sort of templating engine. EJS is one option. There is also [Pug](https://pugjs.org), [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) and a ton of others.

---

The other option is to render static HTML and write some client side javascript to fetch raw data from the server. To do this, you would:

1. Create another route in your express application that returns JSON with movie data
2. Create a static HTML file served from a public directory.
3. Create client side javascript loaded by your static HTML file which fetches the server routes that returns your JSON then updates your page based on the results (possibly via React, Angular, jQuery, or simply `someElement.innerHTML = foundMovie`)